# jQuery incrementing value of css property after animate on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have a effect of appear from bottom and fade to bottom, based in the property margin-top of the element, but I don't have the result that I want. It works fine at first time, fade In and Out. But when I execute it for the second time, the value of the property is 10px bigger than it supposed to be. And every time that I click to apper and fade out, when I click to appear again it has 10px more than the last time. What should I do don't increment this value? The code is above. Somebody help me, please! Thanks.

```
$(document).on("click",".nav-menu",function(){
    var $initial_margin_top = $(".w-clearfix.nav-menu-ul").css("margin-top"); 
    var $margin_num = parseInt($initial_margin_top.split("px")[0]) + 10; 
    if($(this).hasClass("nav-menu-hover")){ 
        $(".w-clearfix.nav-menu-ul").animate({"margin-top": $margin_num+"px","opacity":"0"}); 
        $(".w-clearfix.nav-menu-ul").css({"margin-top": $initial_margin_top});
        $(this).removeClass("nav-menu-hover");
    }else if(!$(this).hasClass("nav-menu-hover")){ 
        $(this).addClass("nav-menu-hover");  
        $(".w-clearfix.nav-menu-ul").css({"margin-top": $margin_num+"px" ,"opacity":"0"});
        $(".w-clearfix.nav-menu-ul").removeClass("hide");
        $(".w-clearfix.nav-menu-ul").animate({"margin-top": $initial_margin_top,"opacity":"1","margin-left":"-1px"}); 
        $(".w-clearfix.nav-menu-ul").css({"margin-top": $initial_margin_top});
    }
});
```

Comment: Would you create a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of this code? it hard to understand the problem otherwise

Comment: You might want to add an If statememt to check if the 10 has already been added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem resides in this line of code:

```
var $margin_num = parseInt($initial_margin_top.split("px")[0]) + 10;
```

Every time your nav-menu item is clicked, the initial value is incremented by 10, because it is inside your click handler.

To prevent this, declare your inital margin outside the click function once.

Comment: I changed the code to increment the value only when I use it, `$(".w-clearfix.nav-menu-ul").animate({"margin-top": ($margin_num+10)+"px","opacity":"0"}); ` and the variable $margin_num receive only the value of the margin-top of the element. But still not working...

Comment: What happens is, if you animate using jQuery, your elements actual CSS get's changed. Now if you consider your code, every time you click, you animate to your margin-top + 10. So the next time you click, your variable $inital_margin_top will be set to this new top-value (your old one + 10). That's the reason why it keeps adding 10.

Now, to prevent this, as I said, make sure to declare the inital value OUTSIDE your click handler. This way, the value is set ONCE, and never changed. You can then always use it inside your click handler to reset your element you want to animate.

Good luck!

Comment: Oh and if you really want to use smooth animation, try looking into CSS3 Transitions. There's ways to use hardware acceleration to make your animation way smoother than with javascript. Here's a link to get started: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: Thank you, I declared it before call the function, I was doing something wrong, thinking that I should pass the value like `function($margin)`but I had only to declare it before call the function, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

This line is your issue:

```
var $margin_num = parseInt($initial_margin_top.split("px")[0]) + 10;
```

The problem is that you increment the value each time without resetting it. You need to somehow store the original value and revert back to it each time this function runs.

First thing that comes to mind, is to store the original value in an attribute inside the element you are changing, give it a name like '`data-num`'. So you can have for example:

```
<div width="50px" data-num="50px"></div>
```

Good luck.

Comment: I changed the code to increment the value only when I use it, `$(".w-clearfix.nav-menu-ul").animate({"margin-top": ($margin_num+10)+"px","opacity":"0"}); ` and the variable $margin_num receive only the value of the margin-top of the element. But still not working...

Comment: If you increment value only when you use it, you will still have the same problem; you need to 'reset' the value to default every run.